# Tunnel from my home computer using my server

Tags: ssh, localhost, tunnel

I have a local webserver in my Mac (OS X 10.7.3). I was wondering how could I build a tunnel to "publish" it temporarily on the internet. For example, my server is running on localhost:20000 and I want it to be able through my VPS's domain name, let's say, on my-domain.com:20000.

So like

```
LOCAL:20000 -> SERVER:20000 -> INTERNET
```

I tried a SSH Tunnel `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:20000:my-domain.me:20000 root@my-domain.me` but I get

```
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 25565
Could not request local forwarding.
```

And then the usual prompt :(. How can I achieve it?